# Login sound disabled

Tags: 12.04, login, startup

I'm using `Ubuntu 12.04` on my `Lenovo G550`. I noticed that `Ubuntu` disabled the startup sound played after login (I love it). I did some Googling and found on [UbuntuGeek](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/) that we have to add this command

```
 /usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id=”desktop-login” --description=”GNOME Login sound”
```

to Startup Applications. I did that but I still don't hear the sound.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If that's the case you could accept that answer so this question is marked as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some odd reasons command available on [Ubuntu Geek](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-enable-startup-login-sound-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise.html) is not working, But the following command is working for me.

`/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id="desktop-login" --description="GNOME Login"`

**How to setup?**

- Click on Gear icon (Session indicator) in Unity panel, And open "Startup Applications".

[image]

- Click add and fill out as follows

```
Name: GNOME Login Sound
Command: /usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id="desktop-login" --description="GNOME Login"
Comment: Plays a sound whenever you log in
```

[image]

- Click save and logout. That's it!

Comment: I think the question poster means the [old login/start up sound](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQaEXZ-df6Y). Your answer only indicates how to enable/disable the new login sound in 12.04.

Comment: The funny thing is that is "ON" but I still don't get the sound

Comment: Yes @rearlight, that's what I mean - the "old login/start up sound"

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem and after hours of searching I've found a solution to the following problem:

1. I could not select any alert sounds - they were greyed out.
2. using `canberra-gtk-play --id="desktop-login"` resulted in: Playing sound failed: Sound disabled

Solution:

With dconf-editor (package dconf-tools) select org.gnome.desktop.sound. Select the event-sounds so it is marked: **Do not use the default button!** Yes that's weird! Even though the default button sets the check box to true -it will not work. The check box has to be selected manually (well by mouse :-)

After that I had all alert sounds I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I've run the command `/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id="desktop-login" --description="GNOME Login"` in a terminal and it did something, but I did not hear any sound.

There are 2 possible workarounds:

1. **Experimenting with the `--volume` option** (did not work for me)

   You can change the command to `/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id="desktop-login" --description="GNOME Login sound" --volume=10` and see if you can hear anything then. Higher values are possible.
2. **Changing the login sound command entirely** (worked for me)

   You can create a startup application as indicated by Basharat and as command use this: `paplay /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/desktop-login.ogg`

   For Name and Comment, you can fill in what you want.

I hope that could help.

EDIT: I've used the wrong quotes first, but I still hear nothing when I use `/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id="desktop-login" --description="GNOME Login"` in a terminal. So the command definetly doesn't work for me.

Comment: 2.  Is the boy for me!

Comment: The problem is the quotes were different. that's why the sound didn't come

Comment: @PratyushNalam Man, damn german keyboard layout.. I will edit my answer. Thanks for your hint!

Comment: reboot. after reboot, it worked for me